# Very weird jSON ajax response from IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, internet-explorer-9, cross-domain

**I have searched the web for many many solutions for IE9 ajax cross domain issues and couldn't find any solution.**

The url I use for the ajax call looks like this (this is cross domain since my domain looks like www.domain.com):

```
"http://some.domain.com/folder//api/12c63101-5d02-ab70-6e2a-4519ed75a0fd/rename?accept=json"
```

the ajax call looks like this: (I have tried adding/removing crossDomain/type and whatever I could think of)

```
$.ajax({
        url:url,
        dataType:'json',
        type: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        success:function(data){}
        complete : function(data) {}})
```

This is a lovely response from chrome (the request should have failed this time):

```
 {errorCode: -3997, errorDescription: "[runtime][RECOVERABLE] failed, name [] taken", success: false, payload: null}
```

**but this is the weird response from IE9**

```
LOG: {
readyState : 0,
setRequestHeader : function(a,b){if(!s){var c=a.toLowerCase();a=m[c]=m[c]||a,l[a]=b}return this},
getAllResponseHeaders : function(){return s===2?n:null},
getResponseHeader : function(a){var c;if(s===2){if(!o){o={};while(c=bH.exec(n))o[c[1].toLowerCase()]=c[2]}c=o[a.toLowerCase()]}return c===b?null:c},
overrideMimeType : function(a){s||(d.mimeType=a);return this},
abort : function(a){a=a||"abort",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this},
done : function(){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this},
fail : function(){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this},
progress : function(){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this},
state : function(){return e},
isResolved : function(){return!!e},
isRejected : function(){return!!e},
then : function(a,b,c){i.done(a).fail(b).progress(c);return this},
always : function(){i.done.apply(i,arguments).fail.apply(i,arguments);return this},
pipe : function(a,b,c){return f.Deferred(function(d){f.each({done:[a,"resolve"],fail:[b,"reject"],progress:[c,"notify"]},function(a,b){var c=b[0],e=b[1],g;f.isFunction(c)?i[a](function(){g=c.apply(this,arguments),g&&f.isFunction(g.promise)?g.promise().then(d.re,
promise : function(a){if(a==null)a=h;else for(var b in h)a[b]=h[b];return a},
success : function(){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this},
error : function(){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this},
complete : function(){if(c){var a=c.length;m(arguments),i?k=c.length:e&&e!==!0&&(j=a,n(e[0],e[1]))}return this},
statusCode : function(a){if(a){var b;if(s<2)for(b in a)j[b]=[j[b],a[b]];else b=a[v.status],v.then(b,b)}return this},
status : 0,
statusText : "No Transport"
```

}

(The IE9 response triggers `SCRIPT1014: Invalid character` in the code when I try to parse it as JSON since it is obviously not a JSON...)

Something to do with "No Transport"? With cross domain issues?

UTF-8? (already declared`$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" , contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"});`

I am hopeless - can someone advice?

Comment: If it's a cross domain request you cannot use dataType:'json' , you have to use  dataType:'jsonp'  or CORS

Comment: what do you mean by CORS? can you give me an example of how to write it?

Comment: and it works on chrome? why shouldn't it work on IE9?

Comment: Check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: I see in the header of the response in chrome that I already have "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" so that means core is on

Comment: What happens if you set your data type to jsonp and add &callback= to the end of your url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; // force cross-site scripting (as of jQuery 1.5)
```

And see if it helps.